# implementing bookmark in source code using vim

Tags: vim, plugins

I use this format when coding, it's quite useful for me.

```
# this is python code

# Table                                                                      
#                                                                             
# String_Methods
# String_Slicing 
# String_is_immutable                                                         
# User_Input                                                                  
# Case_Conversion                                                             
# Modifying_String   

 ...

### Modifying_String ###
s.rindex('spam')
s = 'mybacon'
s[2] = 'f' # error

s = s[:2] + 'f' + s[3:]
s   # 'myfacon'

s = 'mybacon'
s = s.replace('b', 'f')
s   # 'myfacon'
```

Because I'm using vim, I can go into chapter I want by pressing * upon M starting with Modifying.

In chapter 'Modifying_String', I can go to Table by repeating this.

Is there a better way than this? to implement something like bookmark..

Comment: Look up `:help mark`. You can mark a line using `m<any char>` then go back to that line whenever you want using `\`<same char>`. NOTE: usage of `\`` character while going to a mark.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use marks for this. There are local marks (lower case letters) and global marks (upper case). Mark with `m` and a letter. `'` and that letter will take you back to the line; using backtick instead will take you to the line and column.

You may need to make sure marks persist using viminfo if you want to use marks

You can also use tags (universal ctags is my favorite implementation) and the various tag commands. This works best for declarations of functions or classes, but doesn’t require remembering which mark is where or jumping between a table of contents.

Lastly, there are a few “outline” style plugins that use tags or other mechanisms to build tables of contents. I don’t use them and cannot offer advice here.